# what is (3 + 9 + 27 + ... + 3^n) in theta notation?

Tags: math, runtime, analysis

Intuitively, I would think it simplifies to theta(3^n).

But I am not sure because I cannot convince myself that everything from 3^0 to 3^(n-1) doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It's more suited for [math.se] instead.

Comment: Maths question.  Off-topic

Comment: You are asking for `sum(3^i, i = 0 ... N)`.  (It is `O(3^n)` which is the same as `O(exp(n))` ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is **finding time complexity of a program**. But is more mathematical. You should **avoid asking on StackOverflow**. You can ask on `math.stackexchange`.

It is just finding the sum of the geometric progression and we need to find the sum of n terms.

```
s(n) = a1(1-r^n)/(1-r)   where r=common ratio and a1 is first term.

s(n) = 3(1-3^n)(1-3)
     = (3-3^(n+1))/-2
     = (3^(n+1)-3)/2
     = (3^n+1)/2     (appox)
     = 3^n+1       (appox)
     = O(3^n)    (appox)
```

Hence you can say that **time complexity** is **θ(3^n)**.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed solution.
I will take note of math.stackexchange for the future :D

Comment: Yeah thats nice of you thanks. You can select answer if it solved your queries.